# Generate hash for unique combination

Tags: php

I have a joining table in a database which links different entities together, and they can be stored in either order. So, you could have:

```
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
12345   |67890
```

or

```
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
67890   |12345
```

This would be seen as the same association, the order is irrelevant.

I'm curious on the best way to create a hash which would be the same regardless on what order the IDs were passed through.

This is the best I can think of:

```
function relationship_hash()
{
    $params = func_get_args();
    sort($params);
    return md5(implode(',', $params));
}
```

So relationship_hash(12345,67890) and relationship_hash(67890,12345) would both generate the same hash. This could take any number of values and find a hash for that combination.

Regardless of whether or not the database design is efficient, I'm just curious on methods to generate a hash for this sort of use-case.

Comment: I think that sorting them has answered your own question. As long as the hash is generated with the values in order in PHP, it's golden.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an unordered [pairing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) to create an unique number from two other number. The argument order doesn't matter.

```
function relationship_hash($n1, $n2) {
    $ret = $n1*$n2+((abs($n1-$n2)-1)^2)/4;
    return md5($ret); // maybe you don't want to use md5 for this
}

echo relationship_hash(12345, 67890), "\n"; // 75071b9bb02d1d75350bd6b926f323f8
echo relationship_hash(67890, 12345), "\n"; // 75071b9bb02d1d75350bd6b926f323f8
```